# How do I re-number rows when I reach a certain number?

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

I want to create two tiered set of row numbers for all the items contained within a group.  For example I would like to number all the cities in a state, but group them in sets of 3.  The end result would look something like this:

```
STATE | NUM1 | NUM2 | CITY
-------------------------------------
NY    | 1    | 1    | Albany
NY    | 1    | 2    | Buffalo
NY    | 1    | 3    | Syracuse
NY    | 2    | 1    | Rochester
NY    | 2    | 2    | Ithaca
```

... and so on.  I want to limit NUM2 to 3, but let NUM1 go as high as necessary.  What I'm using now:

```
SELECT
    STATE,
    CITY,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STATE ORDER BY CITY) AS CITY_NUM
FROM
    T1
;
```

This is OK but for "states" that have a lot of "cities" I am getting some very high numbers and want everything to fit within three columns horizontally.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just use integer arithmetic:

```
SELECT STATE, CITY,
       1 + FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STATE ORDER BY CITY) - 1)/ 3) AS CITY_NUM_1,
       1 + MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STATE ORDER BY CITY) - 1, 3) AS CITY_NUM_2
FROM T1;
```

For the required scenario, with test data the query would work as follows:

```
WITH TAB AS 
(
  SELECT 'NY' STATE, 'Albany' CITY FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'NY' STATE, 'Buffalo' CITY FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'NY' STATE, 'Syracuse' CITY FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'NY' STATE, 'Rochester' CITY FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'NY' STATE, 'Ithaca' CITY FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'IN' STATE, 'Mumbai' CITY FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'IN' STATE, 'Chennai' CITY FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'IN' STATE, 'Delhi' CITY FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'IN' STATE, 'Kolkatta' CITY FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT STATE, CITY,
   1 + FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STATE ORDER BY CITY) - 1)/ 3) AS CITY_NUM_1,
   1 + MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STATE ORDER BY CITY) - 1, 3) AS CITY_NUM_2
FROM TAB;
```